# Match a string that has lowercase char followed by the same character in uppercase

Tags: regex, sed

Strings that should match:

```
foObar
foobBar
```

Should not match:

```
fOobar
foobbar
```

I tried the following without success:

```bash
sed -nE '/([a-z])\U\1/p' <<<foObar
```

Comment: As far as I know, `sed` doesn't support changing case in the search section. You can use Perl instead: `perl -ne 'print if /([a-z])\u\1/' ip.txt`

Comment: This perl statement returns "foobbar" and shouldn't.

Comment: You're right, seems like it doesn't work on backreferences. Try `perl -ne 'print if /([a-z])(?!\1)(?i:\1)/' ip.txt`. This will work with GNU grep too: `grep -P '([a-z])(?!\1)(?i:\1)' ip.txt`

Comment: The above grep and perl commands work - thx!

Comment: I noticed that grep -P '([A-Z])(?!\1)(?i:\1)' does the opposite. Which regex could do both? That is: match Oo as well as oO. Thx!

Comment: I found the answer: perl -ne 'print if /([a-z])(?!\1)(?i:\1)/ or /([A-Z])(?!\1)(?i:\1)/'

Comment: Regex supports `|` to specify alternate patterns. But in this case, you can use `([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)(?i:\1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `GNU grep` and PCRE option:

```bash
$ cat ip.txt
foObar
foobBar
fOobar
foobbar

# lowercase followed by uppercase version
$ grep -P '([a-z])(?!\1)(?i:\1)' ip.txt
foObar
foobBar

# either case followed by the opposite case
$ grep -P '([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)(?i:\1)' ip.txt
foObar
foobBar
fOobar
```

- `(?!\1)` is a negative lookahead that helps to avoid same case as the next character
- `(?i:\1)` makes the backreference case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed`:

```bash
sed -E 'h;s/[A-Z]+/\n&/g;/(.)\n\1/I!d;x' file
```

`h`old the original pattern space. Insert a newline between potential matches. If the is no case-insensitive match of `<char><newline><same char>`, then delete. Otherwise swap back to the original pattern space before printing.

For either case followed by same letter of opposite case:

```
sed -E 'h;s/[A-Z]+|[a-z]+/\n&/g;/(.)\n\1/I!d;x' file
```